# Tessellate polygon geometry in a Python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, tesselation

Is there a way to [tessellate a polygon geometry object](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#tessellate), by using an existing method/function? A function call similar to `feature.geometry().tessellate()`. I know that there's an existing script in the toolbox which does this but I'm trying to avoid creating unnecessary layers by using `processing.run("3d:tessellate,...)`.

And a related side question. Where can I find the existing `3d:tessellate` script in my computer? I couldn't find it in `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis`  which is where most of the other scripts are located. I was hoping to look into the code to see how it was implemented.